# FriendPickerViewController not loading

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk

I am using sdk 3.1 and trying to use the friendpickercontroller but for somehow table is loading empty on my app.

This is my code, can you give hints on the reason?

Thanks

```
    - (void) loadFacebookFriendsPicker:(UINavigationController *)senderNavigationController {

    if (!FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
        // if the session is closed, then we open it here, and establish a handler for state changes
        [FBSession.activeSession openWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                             FBSessionState state,
                                                             NSError *error) {
            switch (state) {
                case FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed:
                {
                    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                                        message:error.localizedDescription
                                                                       delegate:nil
                                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
                    [alertView show];
                }
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }];
    }

    if (self.friendPickerController == nil) {
        // Create friend picker, and get data loaded into it.
        self.friendPickerController = [[FBFriendPickerViewController alloc] init];
        self.friendPickerController.title = @"Pick Friends";
        self.friendPickerController.delegate = self;
    }

    [self.friendPickerController loadData];
    [self.friendPickerController clearSelection];

    [senderNavigationController pushViewController:self.friendPickerController animated:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't your friendPickerController be in the completion handler? The way you're doing it now, friendPickerController would be nil when you'd access it because the completion handler executes asynchronously.

Move your friendPickerController login into the switch case block with condition FBSessionStateOpen. Something like this:

```
switch (state) {
        case FBSessionStateOpen: {

if (self.friendPickerController == nil) {
        // Create friend picker, and get data loaded into it.
        self.friendPickerController = [[FBFriendPickerViewController alloc] init];
        self.friendPickerController.title = @"Pick Friends";
        self.friendPickerController.delegate = self;
    }

    [self.friendPickerController loadData];
    [self.friendPickerController clearSelection];

    [senderNavigationController pushViewController:self.friendPickerController animated:YES];

}
```

(Not sure about calling pushViewController here though)

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to have this function in your app Delegate

```
// FBSample logic
// In the login workflow, the Facebook native application, or Safari will transition back to
// this applicaiton via a url following the scheme fb[app id]://; the call to handleOpenURL
// below captures the token, in the case of success, on behalf of the FBSession object
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {
    return [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication];
}
```